# How can I "store" an operator inside a variable in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm looking for a way to do this in Perl:

```
$a = "60"; $b = "< 80";

if ( $a $b ) {  then .... }
```

Here, `$b` "holds" an operator...  can I do this?  Maybe some other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$a = "60"; $b = "< 80";
if( eval($a. $b)){
  print "ok";
}
```

see [perldoc eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) for more

Comment: Please note that above eval form is not safe if any of those values came from an untrusted source.

Answer (score 19):

It's nice to see how people discover functional programming. :-)

Luckily, Perl has capabilities to create and store functions on-the-fly.  For example, the  sample in your question will look like this:

```
$a = "60"; $b = sub { $_[0] < 80 };

if ( $b->($a) ) { .... }
```

In this example, a reference to the anonymous subroutine is stored in `$b`, the sub having the same syntax for argument passing as a usual one.  `->` is then used to call-by-reference (the same syntax you probably use for references to arrays and hashes).

But, of course, if you want just to construct Perl expressions from arbitrary strings, you might want to use [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

```
$a = "60"; $b = " < 80";

if ( eval ("$a $b") ) { .... }
```

However, doing this via `eval` is not safe, if the string you're eval-ing contains parts that come as user input.  [Sinan Ünür](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100754/sinan-unur) [explained it perfectly in his answer-comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486572/how-can-i-store-an-operator-inside-a-variable-in-perl/2487186#2487186).

Answer (score 8):

How about defining a function that wraps the needed condition:

```
my $cond = sub { $_[0] < 80 };

if ( $cond->( $a ) ) { 
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This should be a comment but comments are too cramped for something like this so I am making it CW.

For the case which you showed where the contents of the variables that are going to be passed to [string eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), the accepted solution is correct.

If, however, the contents of `$a` and `$b` come from user input, then take a look at the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $x = '80';
my $y = '; warn "evil laugh!\n"; exit';

if ( eval ($x . $y) ) {
    print "it worked!!!\n";
}
```

If the strings are entered by the user, there is nothing preventing the user from passing to your program the string `';system "rm -rf /bin"'`.

So, the correct solution to your question would require writing or using an expression parser.

BTW, you should not use `$a` and `$b` as variable names as the are magical package local variables used by [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) and as such they are exempt from [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) — and you **must** always use [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in your programs.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as saying "you **must** always use strict and warnings", but, good answer/comment :)

Comment: @thenduks: I would. One should *fully* understand the ramifications of not using either of those pragmas, and be able to justify the occasion. For beginners, it should not be tolerated.

Comment: I prefer not to talk in generalisms. There's no reason you can't write a one-off script without strict and warnings. It might not be tolerable for you (or, say, people you hire), but others are free to come to their own conclusions.

Comment: @thenduks and if/when you write that script, and you have problems with it due to any of the issues identified by `strict` or `warnings`, and you post your question on a public forum, you will be reminded why you should have used them.

Comment: Again, that's a general statement that may or may not apply to any given situation. Anyway, carry on.

Comment: +1 @sinan: Or you could say: if/when you have problems with your script, just enable strict and warnings, before posting to a public forum.

Comment: @Zano the point is not to *appear* as if one is doing the right thing in public but to do the right thing when one is alone with the keyboard.

Comment: @Sinan: You missed my point. Enabling -w and strict will reveal the problems 90% of the time. The idea that anyone would think that these pragmas are for appearance is just plain ridiculous.

Comment: @Zano You missed my point: I've seen cases on SO and other places where people slap a quick `use strict;` on a script (that would not actually compile with `use strict;`) just for appearance sake.

Comment: @Sinan: Well, that wasn't what I was talking about. Oh well, I'll let you have the last word.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if [Number::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Number::Compare) is of any interest here. From the example:

```
 Number::Compare->new(">1Ki")->test(1025); # is 1025 > 1024

 my $c = Number::Compare->new(">1M");
 $c->(1_200_000);                          # slightly terser invocation
```

Answer (score 0):

Safer form if you trust (or can sufficiently validate) $op and don't trust the safety of the inputs:

```
my $compare_x = $user_input_x;
my $compare_y = $user_input_y;
my $op = <some safe non-user-input, or otherwise checked against a safe list>;
if ( eval("\$compare_x $op \$compare_y") )
{
 ...
}
```